# 3D graphics the camera is facing the object

Tags: arcore

I am making an android application with the use of ARCore and I need to know if the camera is currently facing the object and where the object is in relation to the camera, e.g. is it behind the camera, on the left, on the right, so that you can direct the user how to turn to be in front of the promise. I have access to rotatnio, translation and there is a compose method but I don't know what it's doing.
[method compose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPYLf.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
Vector3 cameraPosition = camera.getWorldPosition();
Vector3 objPosition = object.getWorldPosition();
Vector3 direction = Vector3.subtract(objPosition, objPcameraPositionosition);
Quaternion lookRotation = Quaternion.lookRotation(direction, Vector3.up());
```

The above gives you the quaternion which needs to be applied to the camera to make it face the object. You can subtract this from the camera's current world rotation to get the difference and notify the user accordingly.